# How should we tag Dash (the shell)

Tags: discussion, tags

I went to ask a question about Dash (/bin/sh) in Ubuntu to find that "dash" is being used to describe problems with Unity's Dash interface.

Comment: As dash is the default shell for scripting, many of these could probably be tagged [tag:shell-scripting].

Comment: I'm not a power user and sometimes this site makes me feel like a new-born noob, but my guess is 50 to 60% of the users might understand that, but for users like me we would never put Dash with  shell-scripting.  I guess that's why people edit tags.

Comment: Actually, there's no such thing as a default shell for shell scripting. It just depends on the shebang line. In my case, my default is: `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Just to let you know there is the [dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Almquist_shell) shell.

Answer (score 3):

Why not `dash-shell`? That seems to me to be rather destriptive without being over-generic (`shell-scripting`).